# How to call a SSO enabled service via HTTP

Tags: java, http, single-sign-on, http-get, http-status-codes

I have 2 systems( System A, System B )and SSO is conffigured in between them.
System B has exposed a service which we have to consume in System A.
We are sending a HTTP GET request from System A to System B.

How should I send a HTTP GET request to System B where SSO is configured between them.

I have written code to access service, this is returning 400 bad request. Please guide.

```
URL gatewayServiceUrl = new URL("http://192.168.1.5:8020/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BPM_TEST_SERVICE_SRV/GetData1Set?$filter=c eq 'XX'");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) gatewayServiceUrl.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
System.err.println("HTTP STATUS CODE : "+ connection.getResponseCode());
String eccResponse= "";
if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
     eccResponse = this.getDataFromStream(connection.getInputStream());
} else {
     eccResponsethis.getDataFromStream(connection.getErrorStream());

}
```

Comment: Can you add some more details? 
What is System B saying? 400 could be anything. What kind of SSO are you using? SAML 2?

Comment: SYSTEM B is SAP GATEWAY, SSO is of SAPLOGON ticket, can 400 be because of user is not able to authorised because of SSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I escaped URL and it worked... so lesson learned escape URL and BODY always